# Winforms ToolTip is displayed too far from hovered control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I have a WinForms application. All ToolTips are appearing too far below the hovered controls. It happens on tool bars and menus.

[image]

I think the reason is that form's font is changed. It is **MS Segoe UI 9px**.

Is there a solution to move ToolTip to its default place in general for the whole app?

The screen shot is on Windows 8 "Segoe 9px" font. 100% font scaling. The issue appears on other DPI settings and on other windows versions also.

**Edit**

I compared ToolTip position of my app and VS2012 and Chrome. In my app, ToolTip appears one cursor height below the bottom of the cursor. In VS2012 and Chrome, ToolTip appears one cursor height below the hot point of the cursor (about 2 pixels below the cursor).

Cursor not visible in screen shots:

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2**

I checked other winforms apps with default font settings. The ToolTip also appears one cursor height below the bottom of the cursor. It seams this is the default position for winforms. However it doesn't look well compared with other software.

It looks like it can be fixed only with overriding the default ToolTip behavior.

Comment: The screenshot is very misleading, it removed the mouse cursor.  What you *actually* see is that the tooltip is exactly as far away from the control as the mouse cursor is tall.  This just doesn't confuse a user.  

And more practically, a tooltip cannot overlap the mouse cursor.  Not only will the cursor obscure the tooltip text, if you try to fix it then you'll see that the tooltip instantly disappears again.  Don't try to fix it.

Comment: Hans, your comment makes sence, but I do not agree it's normal. See screenshots from VS2012 and Crome: [VS2012](http://s10.postimg.org/hhbz0dr9l/screenshot_102.png)
[Chrome](http://s10.postimg.org/lrqmvywcp/screenshot_103.png)

Answer (score 1):

Default tooltip in winforms toolstrip have several problems. I've built custom toolstrip that has custom tooltip available at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376643/ToolStrip-with-Custom-ToolTip. I am not 100% sure whether it will solve your problem out of box, but you can fully customize how tooltip appears by altering code.